# Export CMD results on a host through ip?

Tags: windows, ssh, telnet, tftp

Is it possible to export the command prompt session result to a host over the network?

Comment: What operating system? And what do you want to happen to those results on the remote host - save them to a file? Pass them as arguments to a new process? Perhaps you could describe in a bit more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: 1.Windows 7 
2.Save the results in a file on a windows machine over the network 
3.No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the location where you want to save the file is accessible over the network, then you can simply use [command redirection](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) to send the output of your command directly to a file. For instance (with the `dir` command):

```
dir > \\SERVER\Path\file.txt
```

If you want to do this multiple times and append the output to the same file each time, use `>>` instead of `>`.

Edit: if the remote machine requires credentials other than those of the logged in user, try this:

```
net use \\SERVER\Path /user:SERVER\username password
your_command > \\Server\Path\file.txt
net use \\Server\Path /d
```

The first line connects to the shared folder using the given **username** and **password**, and the third line disconnects.

Comment: Thank you. What if the Windows machine requires credentials?

Comment: @looi76 By default it should attempt to use the credentials of the currently logged in user, so you could try creating a user with the same credentials on the remote host and giving it the nexessary permissions. But if you need to use different credentials, see the edit in my answer.